# I need to to login in java using this sql to check if account is active

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need SQL query or anyhow i can fix this so before user can login the sql path will check if status is **active** or **blocked** if block can't login but active can. this my code is showing me that i have error in sql it worked very fine if i remove the status path.

```
DebuggerConnct(){
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb1","root","");
        pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from studentstab where SrStudentId=? and password1=?,Status='Active'");
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {System.out.println(e);}}


public Boolean DebugUser(String SrStudentId,String password1){
try{
pst.setString(1, SrStudentId);pst.setString(2, password1);System.out.println(SrStudentId + password1);rs=pst.executeQuery()return rs.next();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error while validating"+e);
    return false;}}
```

Comment: Please format your code.  What you have is unreadable, and there are syntax errors that keep eclipse from autoformatting it, and I'm not going to take the time to do it by hand...

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: The convention in Java is that each statement goes on its own line. Posting an entire method without linebreaks (e.g. `DebugUser`) is simply unreadable.

Comment: Please read the SO [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you are unfamiliar with the markdown syntax.

Comment: i have edited it please give me solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL:

```
select * from studentstab where SrStudentId=? and password1=?,Status='Active'
```

seems invalid to me. How about replacing the `,` with `AND` which would make it SQL again?

```
select * from studentstab where SrStudentId=? and password1=? AND Status='Active'
```